How to dynamically concatenate two columns where row data has multiple values separated by pipe



A
B




TRUE|FALSE|TRUE|TRUE.. so on
151|152|153|154.. so on



Need to decode column a and concatenate with each values of column b. While decoding true should be converted as + and false as -



End result




+151|-152|+153|+154.. so on



Please note, I need to frame SQL query without using Regexp, PLSQL, CTE, Listagg, XML, length, connect.
select case when "column_a" is not not null then decode("column_a", 'TRUE', '+', 'FALSE', '-') else '' END ||
Replace(case when "column_b"bis not null then "column_b" else '' end, '|', concatenate('|', , case when "column_a" is not not null then decode("column_a", 'TRUE', '+', 'FALSE', '-') else '' END ))

But above code didn't produce expected result.

"I need to frame SQL query without using Regexp, PLSQL, CTE, Listagg, XML, length, connect." With these restrictions the question is probably impossible.

Each row of each column will have multiple values separated by pipe..

This data should never have made it into your database. Why is it there? Why don't you have rows for the separate entries? Rather than looking for a way to build a new string, you should fix the data model.

If you must deal with this data and write a query to get that final string, you should write a recursive query (recursive with clause), which, fortunately, is not against the many rules stating what not to use.

If a CTE is against the (odd) rules, I would have thought a recursive CTE would be too...

Oops, yes. I missed that. Yep, CTEs are forbidden, too.


I need to frame SQL query without using Regexp, PLSQL, CTE, Listagg, XML, length, connect.

This makes it very difficult, but you can use a MODEL clause to iterate over the string splitting it up using the string functions INSTR and SUBSTR and then aggregate it in the correct format:
SELECT id,
       MAX(ab) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY key) AS r
FROM   (
  SELECT id, key, ab
  FROM   table_name
  MODEL
    PARTITION BY (id)
    DIMENSION BY (0 AS key)
    MEASURES (
      a,
      b,
      1 AS s_a,
      2 AS e_a,
      1 AS s_b,
      1 AS e_b,
      CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(4000)) AS ab
    )  
    RULES SEQUENTIAL ORDER ITERATE (1000) UNTIL (e_a[ITERATION_NUMBER] < 1)
    (
      s_a[ITERATION_NUMBER] = COALESCE(e_a[ITERATION_NUMBER - 1] + 1, 1),
      e_a[ITERATION_NUMBER] = INSTR(a[0], '|', s_a[ITERATION_NUMBER]),
      s_b[ITERATION_NUMBER] = COALESCE(e_b[ITERATION_NUMBER - 1] + 1, 1),
      e_b[ITERATION_NUMBER] = INSTR(b[0], '|', s_b[ITERATION_NUMBER]),
      ab[ITERATION_NUMBER]  = CASE
                              WHEN ITERATION_NUMBER > 0
                              THEN ab[ITERATION_NUMBER - 1] || '|'
                              END
                              ||
                              CASE SUBSTR(a[0], s_a[ITERATION_NUMBER], 1)
                              WHEN 'T'
                              THEN '+'
                              ELSE '-'
                              END 
                              || 
                              CASE e_b[ITERATION_NUMBER]
                              WHEN 0
                              THEN SUBSTR(b[0], s_b[ITERATION_NUMBER])
                              ELSE SUBSTR(b[0], s_b[ITERATION_NUMBER], e_b[ITERATION_NUMBER] - s_b[ITERATION_NUMBER])
                              END
    )
)
GROUP BY id;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, a, b) AS
SELECT 1, 'TRUE|FALSE|TRUE|TRUE', '151|152|153|154' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'TRUE', '151' FROM DUAL

Outputs:



ID
R




1
+151|-152|+153|+154


2
+151



fiddle

You can give XMLTABLE a try:
with data(id, a, b) as (
    select 1, 'TRUE|FALSE|TRUE|TRUE', '151|152|153|154' from dual union all
    select 2, 'FALSE|TRUE|TRUE|FALSE', '251|252|253|254' from dual
)
select t.*
from data d,
xmltable( 
  'string-join( for $i at $aidx in ora:tokenize($X,"\|"), $j at $bidx in (ora:tokenize($Y,"\|")) where ($aidx = $bidx) return fn:concat($i,$j), "|" )'
  passing replace(replace(a,'TRUE','+'),'FALSE','-') || '|' as "X", b || '|' as "Y"
  columns val varchar2(4000) path '.'
) t
;

